# Extract values from url using React

Tags: reactjs

I'm using React and I need to navigate the user to a profile page, i.e. mydomain.com/profile/myusername but I'm not sure how to extract the 'myusername' from the url?  Snippet of my code are below, please help!

Many thanks

**Routing**

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div>
                    <Route path="/" component={Main} exact />
                    <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} exact />
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

**My hyperlink**

```
<Link to={`profile/${obj.username}`}>{obj.username}</Link>
```

**My profile page**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Profile extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>myusername</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Profile;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to declare your route like:

```
<Route path="/profile/:username" component={Profile} exact />
```

And then in your component you can access the username with:

```
this.props.match.params.username
```

Like this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{ this.props.match.params.username }</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the recent Typescript versions, we have to specify the name and type of the param we want to use.

URL:

```
    http://localhost:3004/user-detail/:username
```

The following way can be used:

```
    const {username} = useParams<{ username: string }>();
```

**Alternative option 1:**

```
    const { username } = useParams() as { 
        username: string;
    }
```

**Alternative option 2:**

Declaring an interface:

```
    interface ParamInterface {
        username: string;
    }
```

Then using that interface inside the component:

```
    const { username } = useParams<ParamInterface>();
```

**Alternative option 3:**

```
    const { username } : any = useParams();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define route as follows:

```
<Route path="/profile/:id" component={Profile} exact />
```

In component :

```
const id = this.props.match.params.idj
```

Answer (score 0):

You may define your route as follows,

```
<Route path="/profile/:username" component={Profile} exact />
```

Then access username in your component,

```
this.props.match.params.username
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do:
first via `useParams()` in `react-router-dom` or via props:

```
<Route path="/profile/:username" component={Profile} exact />
```

And get it via:

```
const username = props.match.params.username || null
```

But i prefer using default useParams() in react-router-dom:

```
let useParam =  {} as any;
    useParam = useParams();
    let Param = useParam.any || false;
```

Good day!